# Using a data pointer with CUDA (and integrated memory)

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda

I am using a board with integrated gpu and cpu memory. I am also using an external matrix library (Blitz++). I would like to be able to grab the pointer to my data from the matrix object and pass it into a cuda kernel. After doing some digging, it sounds like I want to use some form of a zero copy by calling `cudaHostGetDevicePointer`. What I am unsure of is the allocation of the memory. Do I have to have created the pointer using `cudaHostAlloc`? I do not want to have to re-write Blitz++ to do `cudaHostAlloc` if I don't have to.

My code currently works, but does a copy of the matrix data every time. That is not needed on the integrated memory cards.

Comment: Can't you let Blitz++ work on memory that you pre-allocated with cudaHostAlloc? Or does blitz take care of all the memory management per se?

Comment: @JorenHeit That might work initially, but all over our code we use size-changing functions. That means either rewriting blitz++ or hunting down every function call that would change the allocated memory address. Neither sounds very fun...

Comment: does blitz accept STL containers like `std::vector`? If so, you could write a custom allocator that uses `cudaHostAlloc`...

Comment: @JorenHeit That is certanly worth looking into. There are plans to eventually remove blitz, so I think I may wrap blitz in some kind of adapter that ensures proper allocation (as your first comment suggests.) That would make the eventual refactor easier, but it also means I would have to implements expression templates... yuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer has to be created (i.e. allocated) with `cudaHostAlloc`, even on integrated systems like Jetson.

The reason for this is that the GPU requires (zero-copy) memory to be *pinned*, i.e. removed from the host demand-paging system.  Ordinary allocations are subject to demand-paging, and may not be used as zero-copy i.e. *mapped* memory for the GPU.